# Python: Find keywords in a text file from another text file

Tags: python

Take this invoice.txt for example

> Invoice Number
>
> INV-3337
>
> Order Number
>
> 12345
>
> Invoice Date
>
> January 25, 2016
>
> Due Date
>
> January 31, 2016

And this is what dict.txt looks like:

> Invoice Date
>
> Invoice Number
>
> Due Date
>
> Order Number

I am trying to find keywords from 'dict.txt' in 'invoice.txt' and then add it and the text which comes after it (but before the next keyword) in a 2 column datatable.

So it would look like :

col1       -----                 col2

Invoice number  ------            INV-3337

order number       ----         12345

Here is what I have done till now

```
with open('C:\invoice.txt') as f:
    invoices = list(f)

with open('C:\dict.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        dict = line.strip()
        for invoice in invoices:
            if dict in invoice:
                print invoice
```

This is working but the ordering is all wrong (it is as in dict.txt and not as in invoice.txt)

i.e.
The output is

> Invoice Date
>
> Invoice Number
>
> Due Date
>
> Order Number

instead of the order in the invoice.txt , which is

> invoice number
>
> order number
>
> invoice date
>
> due date

Can you help me with how I should proceed further ?

Thank You.

Comment: Are your files small?

Comment: sorry for the late reply : yes they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. You can load your invoice data into a list, and your dict data into a set for easy lookup.

```
with open('C:\invoice.txt') as f:
    invoice_data = [line.strip() for line in f if line.strip()] 

with open('C:\dict.txt') as f:
    dict_data = set([line.strip() for line in f if line.strip()])
```

Now iterate over invoices, 2 at a time and print out the line sets that match.

```
for i in range(0, len(invoice_data), 2):
    if invoice_data[i] in dict_data:
        print(invoive_data[i: i + 2])
```

Comment: the output comes out weird like this : " ['Invoice Date\n', '\n'] " 

and it did not recognize "Order Number"

Comment: @jokol It seems you have extra newlines. Check my edit.

Comment: hey , I was wondering , how can i put this into an excel file or csv file ?
each of the columns in 2 rows.

Comment: @jokol Info on the csv module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: no matter which way I use , I am getting " IndexError : Index out of range "

I will post my code as an answer so you may see...

Comment: @jokol No please don't. Open a new question.

Comment: ok. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45351141/python-get-data-from-a-text-file-and-put-it-in-an-csv-file-list-index-out-of